# How To Check If Notification Is Sent Successfully In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification

I am unable to find in the documentation of how to handle the notification (*what to do if notification is sent successfully or not*)

**NotificationController**

```
public function AskForLevelUp()
{
    $admin = User::where('is_admin', 1)->first();

    $sendNotification = Notification::send($admin, new LevelUpNotification(Auth::user()->id));

    if ($sendNotification->success()) // **HOW TO DO THIS CORRECTLY**
    {
        return back()->with('success', 'Your request has been submitted, please wait for admin confirmation.');
    }
    else
    {
        return back()->with('failure', 'Something went wrong, your request is not submitted. Please try again later.');
    }
}
```

I've also read that send() has *void* return value [**here**](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Notification.html#method_send). Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Why not use exception handling? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Is this gonna work for you? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#notification-sent-event

Comment: @KevinBui I don't understand how to use listener in controller, could you show me?